Is Everywhere doubled line contractible
The Everywhere doubled line is an interesting example of a non-Hausdorff manifold that is homogeneous. It is constructed by adding to every point of $\mathbb{R}$ another one, with the same basis of deleted neighborhoods (see pi-Base or [BG]). When exploring $\pi$-Base I found contractibility of this space to be an interesting and apparently not discussed question.
To clarify the notation, let $X=\mathbb{R}\times\{0,1\}$ ($\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to the real line and $\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$ are "the doppelgangers").
My idea is to take $u_x:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ of the form $u_x(t)=-(x+1)t^2+t+x$. Then $u_x(0)=x$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u_x(0)=1$ and $u_x(1)=0$. It is also crucial that $(x,t)\mapsto u_x(t)$ is a homotopy on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then a homotopy $H:X\times[0,1]\to X$ between identity and a constant map
can be of the form $H((x,i),t):=(u_x(t),\lfloor i(1-t) \rfloor)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $i\in\{0,1\}$, $t\in[0,1]$. It should be continuous, since we "exit every extra point to the right" (so we do not leave its small neighborhood), but can this be elegantly justified? Maybe there is a more straightforward construction?
[BG] Baillif, Mathieu; Gabard, Alexandre, Manifolds: Hausdorffness versus homogeneity, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 136, No. 3, 1105-1111 (2008). ZBL1140.57014.

Let $L = (\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}) \cup \{(0, 1)\} \subset X$. Define $r : X \to L$ by $(x, b) \mapsto (x, 0)$ if $x \neq 0$, and $(0, b) \mapsto (0, b)$ otherwise.
$L$ is homeomorphic to the line with two origins. See the nice page at MathOverflow which shows $L$ is not simply connected. It is clear that $r$ is a retraction, hence it follows by Proposition 1.17 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology that $X$ is not simply connected, which implies that $X$ is not contractible.

Now I see the problem with my construction. Clearly the preimage of a neighborhood of $(x,1)$ is not open, since it cannot contain a neighborhood of $((x,1),0)$ in the product. I guess that the first time we escape $\mathbb{R}\times{1}$ should be a right place to look for a discontinuity of any supposed homotopy on $X$.

Wow - the OP's argument is one of the most convincing but wrong proofs I have seen.  I also thought the key to continuity was consistently sliding to the right (by the way I now cannot get this song out of my head: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZv62ShoStY).  I suppose the key point is that although each path is continuous, the path from $(x,1)$ and the path from $(x+\epsilon,1)$ are "far apart", even for "small" $\epsilon$,  because (for $x,\epsilon >0$) they pass through different "versions" of  $x$: that is $(x,1)$ and $(x,0)$ respectively.
